# Popover arrow after keyboard dismiss

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, popover, uimodalpresentationstyle

I present popover with UITextField in it. Everything works fine (arrow points to sourceRect). Then I tap textfield and keyboard opens. Popover gets moved and arrow direction is changed. That's fine too. But when I dismiss keyboard, arrow remains at same direction.

Here is my simple project https://github.com/sirljan/PopoverArrow

I present it this way:

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender {
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController * vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyPopover"];
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    vc.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view; \\self.view is sender.superview
    vc.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = sender.frame;
    vc.popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown | UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I would like to have arrow only up or down. `popoverPresentationController.arrowDirection` is readOnly so I can't change it when 
`- popoverPresentationController:willRepositionPopoverToRect:inView:` is called. Do you have any suggestion how to set arrow correctly?

[image]

Comment: did you dismiss the popover when keyboard get dismissed?

Comment: No. I expect popover to move to original position as it was before keyboard opened.

Comment: try dismiss popover on textFieldDidEndEditing/textFieldShouldReturn

Comment: I tried it and I can't present it again because presentingViewController is nil in dismiss completion handler.